# Not able to differentiate Pop-up

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have different pop-up with similar className but with different TEXT. I am not able to identify the different pop-up's due to the similarity.

Right now I am using xpath : //*[@id='popupMessageContentDiv']/div[2] ---- (For All Pop-up)

Here is the HTML Code:

```
            <div class="modalContent dynamicWidth">
                <div class="padDiv msgcontent f14">
                    <div class="bld f14 "> text text                         </div>
                    <div class="btnok mr50px mt20px">
                        <a class="simplemodal-close" title="OK"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there anyway to diffrentiate the Pop-up.

Comment: So you mean what you've indicated as `text text` in your HTML code differs from pop-up to pop-up? Meaning that in the second pop-up, the text might be `text2 text2`?

Comment: Yes, I have given example for first pop-up with "text text" and second pop-up "text2 text2".

Comment: Could you edit your question, to reflect that? It's a little hard to read. Also, if you could post some code that you tried on each HTML and show the results and describe how they are different from what you expected, that would be awesome.

Comment: You can use `contains` XPath method, if you now the text you are looking for. For example `//*[@id='popupMessageContentDiv']/div[2][contains(.,'text')]`. BTW, for God's sake, don't use indexes :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich I have used this xpath : //*[@id='popupMessageContentDiv']/div[2][contains(.,'text')]. It is showing unable to identify the element.

Comment: Maybe I was not correct enough. Try to change locator a bit. The point is that `div[2]` has a child with `'some text string'`. You may also try `[contains(text(),'text string in popup')]`. Read more about `contains` method [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains)